# How to set v-model to dynamically coming textarea

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a textarea which is rendered dynamically when the page loads.
It looks like this :

```
<textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" name="symptoms_mlform" id="symptoms_mlform">affective</textarea>
```

I want to have a `v-model` in this textarea. How can I achieve this.

Purpose for this is I have a dropdown in child component, which emits event when something selected. So that event I am using in parent to populate this textarea.

```
<MLSubMenu
v-on:SelectedSymptoms="SelectedSymptoms"
>
</MLSubMenu>


SelectedSymptoms(event){
  $("#symptoms_mlform").text(event);
},
```

The event is handled by `SelectedSymptoms` in parent, which sets the event value to textarea.

The drawback I faced while using this:

1. If you keep selecting the values from dropdown, it will keep coming in textarea.
2. But if you remove anything from textarea and then select from dropdown, it will not show in textarea but if I inspect this textarea, selected values will show there but not reflected in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement by following the below mentioned steps.

**In child component :**

```
SelectedSymptoms(event){
  this.$emit('send-selected-value', 'carrier');
}
```

**In parent component :**

```
<div v-on:send-selected-value="getSelectedValue(e)">
  <textarea type="textarea" v-model="modelValue" class="form-control" name="symptoms_mlform" id="symptoms_mlform">affective</textarea>
</div>

methods: {
  getSelectedValue: function (e) {
    this.modelValue = e;
  }
}
```